# CodeIgniter undefined variable $config

Tags: php

```
function index()
{
$this->load->library('email',$config);
}
```

I have work with Codeigniter mail class and i got undefined variable error.

Comment: and then where is `$config` ?

Comment: `$config` doesn't seem to exist in that scope...

Comment: Is there any value in your $config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay jems i thing you just remove $config variable,because it will load automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config
```

Has never been given a value, at least not in the scope that your code is in.

You must do

```
$config = 'foo';
```

or something similar, SOMEWHERE within the scope, to initialize it.

You should also use

```
if(isset($config))
```

to make sure that it actually exists.

Or just use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3f%3a):

```
$config = isset($config) ? $config : 'default';
```

If config is ineed defined somewhere else, then you should pass it as a parameter into the function.

```
index($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

the Codeigniter library load syntax is

you have to try to load email class:

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

if you want to config the mail class in loading time then the syntax is :

```
$this->load->library('email');
// config is 
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

and also try this :

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('email',$config);
```